# PHP: Get Value in array without using a loop

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop

In my application I have duplicated code include foreach. I have a foreach where I only store the value from **$schedules** to new **array**. Then I used another foreach to check if this array is in new $array.

I have an array here `$schedules`:

```
$schedules = [
  [
    "time_start" => "08:00:00",
    "time_end" => "12:00:00",
    "in_threshold" => 50,
    "out_threshold" => 15
  ],
  [
    "time_start" => "13:00:00",
    "time_end" => "17:00:00",
    "in_threshold" => 30,
    "out_threshold" => 45
  ]
];
```

So I have this code snippet using forloop to store to new array:

```
foreach($schedules as $schedule){

    // Set time_start and time_end to array
    $sched_starts[] = ( $schedule[ 'time_start' ] );
    $sched_ends[] = ( $schedule[ 'time_end' ] );

    // Set time_start and time_end with threshold to array
    $time_start[] = date( "H:i:s",
        strtotime('+'. $schedule[ 'in_threshold' ] .' minutes',
            strtotime ( $schedule[ 'time_start' ]
            )));
    $time_end[] = date( "H:i:s",
        strtotime('+'. $schedule[ 'out_threshold' ] .' minutes',
            strtotime( $schedule[ 'time_end' ]
            )));
}
```

I want to get `$sched_starts`,`$sched_ends`,`$time_start`, and `$time_end` without using a loop to avoid duplicated loops. So I used `array_column` and `array_walk_recursive` function but I can't get the **$time_start** and **$time_end** then I realized the two functions only get single column in the $schedules at a time.

Is it possible not to use the `loop` in getting the **$time_start** and **$time_end**?

Comment: There is no interest in using `array_walk_recursive` (or `array_map`) to avoid a for loop, because it uses loops under the hood. The question here is to know what tasks your 2 loops do. If the second needs the full result from the first, you need 2 separate loops. Nothing wrong with it. If the tasks are independent, do the 2 in the same loop. That's why we need the full code to give you advices on this. Another thing, if there is no performance problem in your 2 loops, you shouldn't really bother.

Comment: @Rubics Does my post achieve the goal of avoiding loop? was it helpful or not what you meant?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `end` , which will point to the last element

```
 $c = end($schedules);
 $time_start = $c['time_start'];
 $time_end = $c['time_end'];
```